# How can I add Imgur category to Feedly or Slack RSS?

Tags: rss, slack, rss-reader, imgur, feedly

I'm trying to fetch the latest images/GIFs from an Imgur category `Science_and_Tech` but no luck thus far. The endpoint I'm trying is: https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/Science_and_Tech.rss but when I visit that URL in the browser, I get this JSON response:

> {"data":{"error":"Authentication required","request":"/3/gallery/Science_and_Tech.rss","method":"GET"},"success":false,"status":401}

I've tried with `.json` and `.xml` and I get the same response.

I've created an app on Imgur and generated a client ID and secret key but have no idea where to use them.

All I want is to be able to fetch the latest posts of that specific category.